# How to one hot encode a variable with 3k categories without a MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

I am one-hot encoding a variable that has more than 3k categories and running into MemoryError. I have other variables that I'm one-hot encoding too, but they have fewer categories. The max categories I have for a variable that I can successfully one-hot encode is 935.

I am using the following code:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

def onehot(featurename):
    onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(df[featurename].reshape(-1, 1))
    trn_onehot_encoded = onehot_encoded[msk]
    val_onehot_encoded = onehot_encoded[~msk]
    return trn_onehot_encoded, val_onehot_encoded

trn_onehot_encoded_mt, val_onehot_encoded_mt = onehot('modality_type')
trn_onehot_encoded_mr, val_onehot_encoded_mr = onehot('roleid')
trn_onehot_encoded_sub, val_onehot_encoded_sub = onehot('subject')
trn_onehot_encoded_quartile, val_onehot_encoded_quartile = onehot('quartile')
trn_onehot_encoded_country, val_onehot_encoded_country = onehot('country_short')
trn_onehot_encoded_region, val_onehot_encoded_region = onehot('region')
trn_onehot_encoded_groupmemberornot, val_onehot_encoded_groupmemberornot = onehot('groupmemberornot')
trn_onehot_encoded_highlight, val_onehot_encoded_highlight = onehot('highlight_bin_new')
trn_onehot_encoded_note, val_onehot_encoded_note = onehot('note_bin_new')
trn_onehot_encoded_eid, val_onehot_encoded_eid = onehot('new_eid')
```

The final line of code where I encode the variable `new_eid`, is where I get the `MemoryError` or a dead kernel.

In order to try and resolve this error, I set the field `sparse` to `true` in `OneHotEncoder` in the function `onehot()`.

The code to fit with `Sparse=True` is as follows:

```
<All the code above with Sparse=True>
mt = Input(shape=(trn_onehot_encoded_mt.shape[1],))
mr = Input(shape=(trn_onehot_encoded_mr.shape[1],))
sub = Input(shape=(trn_onehot_encoded_sub.shape[1],))
gmon = Input(shape=(trn_onehot_encoded_groupmemberornot.shape[1],))
region = Input(shape=(trn_onehot_encoded_region.shape[1],))
country = Input(shape=(trn_onehot_encoded_country.shape[1],))
highlight = Input(shape=(trn_onehot_encoded_highlight.shape[1],))
note = Input(shape=(trn_onehot_encoded_note.shape[1],))

#Model definition
x = merge([u, a], mode='concat')
x = Flatten()(x)
x = merge([x, mt], mode='concat')
x = merge([x, mr], mode='concat')
x = merge([x, sub], mode='concat')
x = merge([x, gmon], mode='concat')
x = merge([x, region], mode='concat')
x = merge([x, country], mode='concat')
x = merge([x, highlight], mode='concat')
x = merge([x, note], mode='concat')
x = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(x)
BatchNormalization()
Dropout(0.5)
x = Dense(200, activation='relu')(x)
BatchNormalization()
Dropout(0.5)
x = Dense(50, activation='relu')(x)
BatchNormalization()
x = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
nn = Model([user_in, artifact_in, mt, mr, sub, gmon, region, country, highlight, note], x)
nn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

def fit_nn(lr, bs):
    nn.optimizer.lr = lr        
    nn.fit([trn.member_id, 
        trn.artifact_id, 
        trn_onehot_encoded_mt, 
        trn_onehot_encoded_mr, 
        trn_onehot_encoded_sub, 
        trn_onehot_encoded_groupmemberornot, 
        trn_onehot_encoded_region, 
        trn_onehot_encoded_country,
        trn_onehot_encoded_highlight,
        trn_onehot_encoded_note], trn_onehot_encoded_quartile, 
       batch_size=bs, 
       epochs=1, 
       validation_data=([val.member_id, 
                         val.artifact_id, 
                         val_onehot_encoded_mt, 
                         val_onehot_encoded_mr, 
                         val_onehot_encoded_sub, 
                         val_onehot_encoded_groupmemberornot, 
                         val_onehot_encoded_region, 
                         val_onehot_encoded_country,
                         val_onehot_encoded_highlight,
                         val_onehot_encoded_note], val_onehot_encoded_quartile)
           )


bs = 10000
fit_nn(0.001, bs)
```

But then when I try and fit the model, I get the following error:

```
Train on 2116850 samples, validate on 234276 samples
Epoch 1/1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-8ce1b684763f> in <module>()
----> 1 fit_nn(0.001, bs)

<ipython-input-30-3e1be8cadb04> in fit_nn(lr, bs)
     23                          val_onehot_encoded_country,
     24                          val_onehot_encoded_highlight,
---> 25                          val_onehot_encoded_note], val_onehot_encoded_quartile)
     26            )

/home/prateek_dl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1596                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1597                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1598                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1599 
   1600     def evaluate(self, x, y,

/home/prateek_dl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
   1181                     batch_logs['size'] = len(batch_ids)
   1182                     callbacks.on_batch_begin(batch_index, batch_logs)
-> 1183                     outs = f(ins_batch)
   1184                     if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1185                         outs = [outs]

/home/prateek_dl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2271         updated = session.run(self.outputs + [self.updates_op],
   2272                               feed_dict=feed_dict,
-> 2273                               **self.session_kwargs)
   2274         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2275 

/home/prateek_dl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    893     try:
    894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
    896       if run_metadata:
    897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/prateek_dl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1091             feed_handles[subfeed_t] = subfeed_val
   1092           else:
-> 1093             np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
   1094 
   1095           if (not is_tensor_handle_feed and

/home/prateek_dl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    480 
    481     """
--> 482     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    483 
    484 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am unable to fit the model with sparse or not-sparse arrays. The not soarse arrays give me a MemoryErrror and the Sparse arrays give me the error mentioned above.

How do I resolve this error? There has to be a way I can encode variables with a large number of categories.

Comment: Can you please try to Label encode it first and then One-Hot encode it.